# How do I reference the sepcific object/dom element that an jquery-ui autocomplete function belongs to, when it has been applied to all inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$("input[type=text]").autocomplete({
minLength: 3,
source: function (request, response) {
        alert( $(this).val() );
```

I have 3 different input text box's, but `$(this).attr("id")` or `this.id` both returned undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is available inside `source` regarding `this`. You can always log it to console to see what is returned. The following pattern is helpful for implementing plugins on many elements

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    $(this).autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function(request, response) {
            alert(id);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert( $(this.element).attr("id") );
```

works.